# Create generic groupBy method

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create generic groupBy method from the list of objects that I have so I though my method could have signature something like this :

```
private Map<String, List<T>> groupBy(List<T> list, String fieldName) {
```

But it's not compiling. Type T is missing, how can I fix it to compile? I though of calling the field name(getter) via java reflection and grouping it and returning a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `<T>` at the beginning. Check the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more information

```
private <T> Map<String, List<T>> groupBy(List<T> list, String fieldName) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your type parameter `<T>` in your generic method:

```
private <T> Map<String, List<T>> groupBy(List<T> list, String fieldName) {
    //  ^^^ declare T
    //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private <T> Map<String, List<T>> groupBy(List<T> list, String fieldName) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) (not just a method that accepts generic types)....

Simply add `<T>` after the `private`:

```
private <T> Map<String, List<T>> groupBy(List<T> list, String fieldName) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the definition of the type parameter:

```
private <T> Map<String, List<T>> groupBy(List<T> list, String fieldName) {
```

You may also be interested in checking out Guava's multimaps, and especially the [grouping functionality](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).